# GitHub - Clonar diretório

Tags: git, github

Boa Tarde Pessoal, poderia me ajudar esse erro ao clonar o diretório no git.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já verificou se você tem permissão de escrita nesse diretório?

Comment: Como faço essa verificação?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você tem que fazer as configurações iniciais:

```
$ git config --global user.name "user142009"
$ git config --global user.email user142009@example.com
```

https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Primeiros-passos-Configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Inicial-do-Git

Comment: Obrigado, é isso mesmo.